# ForEach loop not printing the 4 element of the array - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Here's my code -

```js
var a = 'abcde'.split('');
var b = 'cxefgh'.split('');
//abfgh

a.forEach((e, index) => {
  console.log(e, index)
  if (b.indexOf(e) > -1) {
    b.splice(b.indexOf(e), 1);
    a.splice(index, 1);
  }
})

//Here the output -

//a 0
//b 1
//c 2
//e 3
```

Why this loop isn't printing d. What's the silliest thing that I am missing here?

Comment: You are modifying the iterable while iterating. Else said, the index "d" is at changes, while the index `forEach` uses doesn't. This results in the skip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are changing `a` while iterating on it, resulting in discrepancy.
You should consider working on clone of `a` (created with `a.slice()`) and then changing the `a` and `b`, if matches are found.

```js
var a = 'abcde'.split('');
var b = 'cxefgh'.split('');
//abfgh

a.slice().forEach((e , index)=> {
    console.log(e, index)
    if(b.indexOf(e) > -1) {
    b.splice(b.indexOf(e) , 1); // Find where it is in `b` and remove it.
    a.splice(a.indexOf(e) , 1); // Find where it is in `a` and remove it.
  }
})

console.log(a); // ['a', 'b', 'd']
console.log(b); // ['x', 'f', 'g', 'h']
```

Comment: Thanks a ton very nice explanation. I think I need some sleep now! Have a great day.

Answer (score 2):

`a.splice(index , 1);` is executed when `e` is `'c'`. `index` is 2 at that point, so `a` becomes `['a', 'b', 'd', 'e']` (the splice removes the `'c'`). Then the `forEach` moves on with `index` 3, which is (now) `'e'`.

Comment: @J. Pichardo - Thanks, I had **just** fixed that (and added a bit of text) before your edit, so your edit got rejected. (Good edit, though, thanks again.)